# Type a regular mathcal letter while using newtxmath with the libertine option

Tags: libertine, newtxmath, mathcal

I am required to use a .cls that loads the newtxmath package with the libertine option. Because of this (I think), when I type \mathcal{A} my "A" looks different than it normally does. I need to typeset a single normal, non-libertine, old-school \mathcal{A}. A once-off, inline solution that works in a math environment would be ideal. Thanks!

Comment: Does this, in the preamble, help? `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathcal}   {symbols}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathcal}{bold}{OMS}{cmsy}{b}{n}`.  If you also need the new `\mathcal`, as well, you can issue `\let\svmathcal\mathcal` before the above commands, and access the new version with `\svmathcal{...}`.

Comment: There is no “regular mathcal”. Font designers are free to adopt the shape they like. The fact that CM Calligraphic is ubiquitous (for the reason that so many LaTeX documents use Computer Modern) isn't a mark for “officiality” of the symbols. By the way, I don't like them so much and try to avoid them if I can. Besides, `acmart` is specially crafted for the needs of ACM and they won't be so happy to see such changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original `\mathcal` alphabet is from the `cmsy` font.  You can switch to that inside a `\text` command from `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[type1]{libertine}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\newcommand\varcal[1]{\text{\usefont{OMS}{cmsy}{m}{n}#1}}
\newcommand\varcalA{\varcal{A}}

\begin{document}
\[ A \mathcal{A} \varcal{A} \varcalA
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Newtx + Libertine + Computer Modern sample]

You could also declare `\varcal` with `\DeclareMathAlphabet`, which would have the advantage of working with `\boldmath`.  However, you say you don’t need this, and there is a limit on how many math alphabets legacy 8-bit TeX can use.

If you only need two different script alphabets, you could load one as `\mathcal` and the other as `\mathscr` using `mathalpha`.

Comment: Brilliant! You saved my life and taught me something new :)

Comment: The original definition, by the way, is in `cmfonts.fdd` from the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: @the_count_1968 Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem as you, and I found it can be solved by using

```
\usepackage[cal=cm]{mathalfa}
```

Comment: Could you please add a MWE of how your solution works?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!